# Eclipse (on OS X 10.9) defaulting to built-in Ruby 2.0 but need 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, eclipse, macos

On my MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) installed, Eclipse is stuck on using the built-in Ruby 2.0.0 which breaks the ruby script I use as part of my build.

**What I've done**

- I've used rvm and installed 1.8.7
- I've updated ~/.bash_profile to include `rvm use 1.8.7`
- In Project Properties -> Builders -> The ruby script has an entry: *Location* indicates where the script it, *Working Directory* indicates the folder that contains the source data and where the processed data will be saved in, *Arguments* is the command-line arguments

**What I'm getting**

- When I open a new bash terminal I see the message `Using ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374`
- When Eclipse shows the error in the console window, it shows :
  `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in "require": cannot load such file -- plist (LoadError)
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in "require"
  from .....`
- When I execute the ruby script from a terminal, it executes just fine.

**Problem**

- It seems that Eclipse isn't using the ruby 1.8.7 that I've installed - how can I change that ?

**EDIT... my ~/.bash_profile is as follows :**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$PATH #sublime
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
rvm use 1.8.7-p374
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Eclipse insists on using the system ruby (and ignoring my RVM installed Ruby - which was not an issue in OS X 10.7.5 !), I decided to stop fighting it...
`sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/gem install plist` got me the gem I needed

Comment: Worked perfectly to fix an old ruby script that was running as part of an Xcode build.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell rvm which ruby version to use:

```
rvm use 1.8.7-p<package_number>
```

Moreover, assuming you want Ruby 1.8.7 to be your default version as well, you may consider:

```
rvm alias create default 1.8.7-p<package_number>
```

To perform both operations with 1 command:

```
rvm --default use 1.8.7-p<package_number>
```

More information on selecting a default ruby version with rvm can be found here: http://rvm.io/rubies/default

Update: Rather than the .bash_profile, you want to add the 'rvm use 1.8.7-p' command to your .rvmrc or .ruby-version + .ruby-gemset file(s) in the project directory that you want the gemset to apply to; more on creating a .rvmrc/.ruby-version+.ruby-gemset file here: http://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Comment: I've done the `rvm --default use 1.8.7-p374` command in a terminal, but Eclipse still wants to use `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0`. Note: I don't want to do Ruby development in Eclipse, I just want Eclipse to run the ruby script, that's part of the build process, against 1.8.7

Comment: Additionally, why does Eclipse show the path to be `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/` ? When I use `rvm use 2.0.0 --default` followed by `which ruby`, the path shown is `/Users/[me]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby`

Comment: Please verify that the .rvm directory is at the beginning of your PATH environment variable.

Comment: grenierm5 - I've added my `~/.bash_profile` to my original post. It looks OK to me. Running the ruby script, that's part of my android build process, in a bash terminal *does* function. The problem is that Eclipse keeps referring to the system ruby (which seems to be 2.0.0)

Comment: Dang. My bad. I guess I misread your original question. I hope I didn't de-rail your thread too much :/

Comment: after I set default ruby and gemset using rvm, problem solved nicely.